# How to edit default C# .Net Core Templates In Vs2019?

Tags: c#, .net-core, project-template

I've been trying to edit the default .Net core templates installed with vs2019 but I can not find where they are stored I checked:

```
.\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\
```

but that directory only contains .Net Framework project templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the entire directory address of where you checked, so I'll assume you haven't looked in the following locations from the docs. Check these directories, they should contain all the templates installed. I just checked mine, all there.

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<edition>\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\<Language>\<Locale ID>`

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<edition>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\<Language>\<Locale ID>`

**NOTE**: These are ***default*** installation locations! If you installed to a custom path, different drive or if you changed the template location yourself, then obviously they won't be there. If you still can't find them, go into VS and check *Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Locations* and see what it's set to.

Comment: For the first location the paths are the same when I enter that Local ID folder all thats contained in there is SharedProject template. I also checked the Locations in Vs like you said and its pointing to my Vs folder in my documents but literally every sub folder in that directory has no projects templates or files for that matter

Comment: @eUz1HLgf7393 Do you see a bunch of `.vstman` files in the `ProjectTemplates` folder? From there, it should be separated by Language -> Framework -> Type, all separate folders. There is no literal `Local ID` folder, frankly I'm not sure what they meant by that. Make sure you have "Show Hidden Files" enabled in the File Explorer. If they're still not there, go check the location setting as I described.

Comment: There arent any .vstman files theres literally no Project/Item templates used in VS that i can find in the directories you listed and the I checked the folder(s) in the tools/options/projects and solutions/locations strings and still empty. When you say Language->framework I do have a CSharp folder that i've been searching but no framework or type folders (i know you don't literally mean the names of the folders). If it helps I'm running Vs 2019 Community Edition if that makes a difference? ps i also have hidden files checked and still nothing

Comment: For reference, within my `CSharp` folder I have folders such as `Cloud` `Web` `Windows` `Test` `Windows UAP`. Inside of those folders, it varies. A few have a `1033` folder which contains the various other "sub-type" folders (i.e. `ConsoleApplication`, `ClassLibrary`, etc.). Some of them have various templates inside and some look rather empty. All I can recommend is look inside each folder and follow each directory all the way down to the last sub-directory. I have VS 2019 Preview installed FYI. Templates may also be dependent on what packages you installed in VS Installer.

Comment: @eUz1HLgf7393 Check previous comment. What packages do you have installed through VS Installer? By packages I mean the "packs" that you can check for things like "Web Development" , "Game Development", "Windows Dev" , etc.

Comment: I mean Like I have those folders but those are .Net Framework based I was looking for .Net Core Console Application template which I can not find a match for, Let me check the packages real quick

Comment: I have web dev, node js, python dev, .net/C++ desktop dev, .net core dev, c++ linux dev, vs extension dev, and data and processing

Comment: @eUz1HLgf7393 Majority of the templates aren't mutually exclusive for .NET Framework or .NET Core. All the basic templates (Class library, console app, etc.) use the same template regardless of whether you target .NET Framework or .NET Core. So there won't be separate templates for these types of projects. As for ASP.NET Core templates, check under `CSharp/Web/1033`. I think you may be looking for templates that just aren't there and you most likely have all the correct files. Regardless of framework, many project types use the same template as a base.

Comment: @eUz1HLgf7393 If you want the template for a .NET Core Console Application, go to `CSharp/Windows/1033/ConsoleApplication`. That's the template for both frameworks.

Comment: Oh that's probably what it is I've checked everywhere appreciate the help though